# How do I import mecab-python 3 in google colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I'm successfully to install mecab-python3, but I get an error on import.

```
!import mecab
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-71af23e59d14> in <module>()
----> 1 import mecab

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mecab'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

FLY,install mecab-python3 log.

```
!pip install mecab-python3==0.8.0
Collecting mecab-python3==0.8.0
  Downloading         https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/a6/f528e7a07ad9eeaa506d00ef873d3459ff9b7eba52c9615878571dbc0007/mecab-python3-0.8.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mecab-python3
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mecab-python3 ... done
  Stored in directory:     /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b4/b1/14/2c69b99293f4ba56ff03641c3fe449a371338b919ad37e6942
Successfully built mecab-python3
Installing collected packages: mecab-python3
Successfully installed mecab-python3-0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Going off the instructions here:
https://pypi.org/project/mecab-python3/

You'll need a few prereqs:

```
!apt-get install mecab mecab-ipadic-utf8 libmecab-dev swig
```

Then,

```
!pip install mecab-python3==0.8.0
```

Here's a full notebook example:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ofq1kyVhLuGW2WFDbGVukWVOh5pWTKWz

Comment: Thanks!
I did it according to the instructions.But import will result in an error.

my notebook.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Bm81uSoJQOyERAi0wDvrvZ-A-ex2-cbf

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the mecab-python3 maintainer.

It looks like your problem is that the module is not `mecab` but `MeCab` - note the capitalization.

Note that since v0.996.1, released slightly after this question was asked, you do not need to install any prerequisites. Also version 0.8 is no longer available.

You'll also need to install a dictionary, but you can do it through pip, see [the README](https://github.com/SamuraiT/mecab-python3) for details.